# How to solve error : supported list does not contain required Oid in HCK?

Tags: windows, driver, logo-testing

I done Hardware certification test using HCK from windows . But I got some failed test after done a test .

```
 error : supported list does not contain required Oid
 Error Type: NT_STATUS
 Error Code: 0x53e6
 Error Text: Error 0x000053e6
```

I setup with 2 client (win 7 32 bit ) and server (win server 2012 r2) . Done all setting using HCK guide .Updated filters also But same failed scenario . How to solve this test error ? is it coding mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error with a global array of supported list . I was created a supported array with new operator . After removing this ,i can bale to solve this error .